# How does ISO8583 knows if the balance is enough or not from sender's side?

Tags: transactions, iso

Say we're doing a Fund Transfer between 2 different banks. How'd ISO8583 (an old protocol) know if there's enough balance from sender's side?

I haven't noticed "balance" packet being sent from ISO8583 protocol.

I asked my team and they said the check for "if there is enough balance or not" is done by ISO itself without extra request and response for balance. So, was wondering how's that possible?